# Foundation Dropdown on reveal modal: Dropdown is not shown

Tags: knockout.js, drop-down-menu, modal-dialog, zurb-foundation

I have this example that I try to open a dropdown within a reveal modal (for various reasons I must do it like this.) But for an unknown reason the dropdown is not shown. The version of foundation I must use (my boss says so) is the version 5.5.1.

How can I resolve this?

JavaScript:

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.modal = {
      init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        $(document).on('closed.fndtn.reveal', '[data-reveal]', function() {
          if (this === element) {
            valueAccessor()(false);
          }
        });

        var open_binding = allBindings.get('on_modal_open') || null;
        $(document).on('open.fndtn.reveal', '[data-reveal]', function() {
          if (typeof open_binding === 'function') open_binding();
        });
      },
      update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var newVal = valueAccessor()();
        if (newVal) {
          $(element).foundation('reveal', 'open');
        } else {
          $(element).foundation('reveal', 'close');
        }
      }
    };

function Reveal()
{
  var self=this;
  self.showModal=ko.observable(false);
  
  self.reveal=function()
  {
    self.showModal(true);
  }
  
  self.value=ko.observable(0);
  
  self.duplicate=function()
  {
    self.value(2*self.value())
  }
  
  self.inc=function()
  {
    self.value(self.value()+1)
  }
}

ko.applyBindings(new Reveal());
```

HTML (part of it):

```
Value:<span data-bind="text:value"></span><br>
<a data-bind="click:reveal" > Reveal Modal</a>



    <div data-bind="modal:showModal" class="reveal-modal tiny" data-reveal >
    <a data-dropdown="drop1" aria-controls="drop1" aria-expanded="false">Has Dropdown</a>
<ul id="drop1" class="f-dropdown" data-dropdown-content aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1">
  <li><a href="#" data-bind="click:duplicate">Double value</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-bind="click:inc">Inc value</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

The example is on http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YWKaxr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any element that lands in the DOM must be "activated" by a `.foundation(...)` call. The custom binding handler you already have does this for just the modal stuff. You need it to do the contents of the modal as well, e.g.:

```
update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
    var newVal = valueAccessor()();

    $(element).foundation(); // New!

    if (newVal) {
      $(element).foundation('reveal', 'open');
    } else {
      $(element).foundation('reveal', 'close');
    }
}
```

You may need to finetune that new call a bit to your liking/context.

See [this pen fiddle](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mEbKby).

Alternatively, and probably a bit prettier, you could create a seperate custom binding handler for bootrstrapping zurb foundation dropdowns.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the view model and the foundation like this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  ko.applyBindings(new Reveal());
  $(document).foundation();  
})
```

Comment: Although that'll work, I recommend against it, because the `.foundation()` call isn't "live" and will miss out on foundation based elements added to the DOM later (e.g. through an `if` or `foreach` knockoutjs binding). Doing the `.foundation()` calls inside custom binding handlers is a much safer approach.